# Samba server error message in Windows XP

Tags: linux, windows-xp, samba, rhel5

We have a RHEL5 Linux Server with few Windows XP client boxes.

Using Samba server for share files between systems.

My server working well in all systems but one Windows XP machine didn't connect to server.

Here i give some screen shots for clear idea,

[image]

For Check network connection i use ping, It working well.

[image]

I use above way for connect to server. For all other systems it working well.

[image]

I am getting error message like this.

** I am using squid for proxy in Linux, For me internet also working well in that Windows XP system.

** I Deleted stored user name and password for samba in windows XP.

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Your smb.conf would be helpful. This could be due to a myriad of different things. Is there a firewall rule on the server that would drop packets from this stations IP, does it have a stale share on it (net use), etc, etc.

Comment: Can you telnet to port 445 of the server? I think Windows-syntax is: start telnet, then "open //10.1.1.1 445". If you can telnet, this would rule out some potential issues.

Comment: @sinping, This same IP working well in another system. Also working IP of other system too not work in problem system...

Comment: Is samba a domain controller or stand alone server? Any secure channel errors on the client?

Comment: @sinping, I am using samba server for just local sharing, have squid proxy and samba server.

Comment: What do the logs say on the Samba server for that machine? Some samba installations make a log file for each client/IP that connects to it. Can the user account being used on that machine connect from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared this problem. Problem in network adopter drivers. After reinstalling driver , samba server working well.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we're sure about Virus presence?
Which Service Pack?
Smells like Conficker...

To be totally sure try to open \localhost\